# NodeJS Express HTML hidden input value showing only first word

Tags: html, node.js, express, hidden-field

I have a node js app which uses EJS as the template engine.  On several pages I use hidden inputs and access their values using req.body.  I've setup my body parser in express and everything works great.  However, it seems as though any hidden inputs that have a value that is more than one word only display the first word.

So for example my hidden input with `name = "eventname"` has value: "Sample hidden text".  When I do `req.body.eventname` in my express route I get "Sample".  To test I changed the value of my hidden input to "Sample_hidden_text" and in that case `req.body.eventname` comes through as "Sample_hidden_text".  Do hidden inputs not allow spaces in the value?

Below is sample code.  The value of event.name from the console log in page.ejs gives the correct value of "Sample hidden text".  However, the console log in the post route gives "Sample".

Page.ejs

```
    <form action="/addnewresult" method="POST">
<% console.log("the value of event.name hidden field", event.name) %>
           <input type="hidden" name="eventname" value=<%= event.name %>>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

App.js

```
var express                     = require("express"),
    bodyParser                  = require("body-parser")
var app = express();


 app.post("/addnewresult", function(req,res){
    console.log("this is req.body in the post call:  ",  req.body);

    DBhandler.CreateResult(req,res,function(callback){
        //do some stuff here
    });
 });
```

Comment: Post a sample template and a sample server

Comment: Please post Some code so we can look at.

Comment: Code and clarifications added.

Comment: Are there really no quotation marks around the `<%= event.name %>`? If so, that's your problem. You could even check the page source code (Ctrl+U in Chrome) to see what is actually being rendered.

Comment: Brilliant!!! That was it.  I didn't realize it was necessary in order to for the whole value to show since I only had one word values everwhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is just summary coming from Andrew Myers in the comment.
It is needed to use quotations -> `"<%= event.name %>"` instead of just `<%= event.name %>` to get the whole text displayed and not only the first word.

Thank Andrew Myers, it helped me also!